# Why does my sum always results in 0? Sum of 2 integers

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()

{

  int a,b,sum;

  printf("enter two integers:");

  scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
  
  printf ("%d + %d = %d",a,b,sum);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `sum=a+b;` here:

```
scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
sum=a+b;
printf ("%d + %d = %d",a,b,sum);
```

You need to assign the value you need to the variable.

Comment: What this answer adds to the @Eric's one?

Comment: And what will happen when scanf falis?

Answer (score 3):

The code never assigns a value to `sum`. Add an assignment statement that starts with `sum =`.

Enable warnings in your compiler and elevate warnings to errors.  With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /WX`.

Comment: I would add something about the `scanf` return value